# How to find all the boards name in azure DevOps project using azure DevOps api?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I want to find all the boards for given project using azure DevOps API?

Is there any API available for this ?

In this api its asking to give team name. I want to know all the boards available without giving team name

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/{team}/_apis/work/boards?api-version=6.0
```

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your only way here is make first [call for teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/teams/get%20teams?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/projects/{projectId}/teams?api-version=6.0
```

and then having all teams iterate through the list and get all boards for each of the team.